# Homomorphic encryption and program obfuscation

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, obfuscation

[Say I want to outsource the computation of $y=f(x)$ without revealing information about $x$, $y$, or $f$.  I thought I'd have to combine homomorphic encryption with some obfuscation $\mathcal{O}$, passing along encrypted data $\mathsf{enc}(x)$ and obfuscated program $\mathcal{O}(f)$ to be homomorphically evaluated $\mathsf{eval}(\mathsf{enc}(x),\mathcal{O}(f))$.

However, the following comment from Section 1.3.1 of [Computing on the edge of chaos: Structure
and randomness in encrypted computation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/610.pdf)

> In addition to encrypting my data, I can encrypt my query f (under the same pk). More
> broadly, I can encrypt a program P , so that the cloud can execute P on unencrypted data
> or data encrypted under the same pk, and output the encrypted result. At first, this fact may
> seem surprising, but it is just an application of Turing’s idea that a program can be viewed
> just another type of data to be processed by a universal Turing machine. (In more modern
> terms, a program can be read and executed by an interpreter program.)

makes it clear that at least in theory one could encrypt a program (e.g. `my_prog.py`) and homomorphically evaluate an interpreter/processor/compiler (e.g. `python`) on the encrypted source.

My question (assuming everything above makes sense) is whether or not this has been done in some form, either abstractly or more concretely.  For instance encrypt the string `2*3+5` and homomorphically evaluate a calculator that takes the input string `2*3+5`, parses, evaluates, and outputs `11`.

[Edit:  I guess the calculator example in the [Google transpilier](https://github.com/google/fully-homomorphic-encryption/tree/main/transpiler) does something along these lines.]

Comment: Try that with an encrypted program that, when run in an appropriate interpreter, finds a good chess move on a chess board position (bonus: with that chess board position encrypted)!